# Spark Scala exception java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol:

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an rdd with the edges list which is comma separated like (source_URL, destination_URL). I have to extract the source host from source_URL. I tried the following code:

```
val edges = links.flatMap{case (src, dst) =>
if (!src.startsWith("http://") || !src.startsWith("https://"))
  { val src_url = "http://" + src 
    val url = new java.net.URL(src_url)
    val uri = url.getHost
    scala.util.Try {
        Some(uri,dst)}
        .getOrElse(None)}
else 
   { val src_url = src
    val url = new java.net.URL(src_url)
    val uri = url.getHost
    scala.util.Try {
        Some(uri,dst)}
        .getOrElse(None)}
```

}

Input sample:

```
http://www.belvini.de/weingut/mID/2530/max-markert.html,http://www.belvini.de/content.php/coID/299/kundenmeinungen.html
http://www.belvini.de/weingut/mID/2530/max-markert.html,http://www.belvini.de/weingueter
http://www.belvini.de/weingut/mID/2530/max-markert.html,http://www.belvini.de/filter/cID/10/country/suedafrika.137.html
```

Required output:

```
www.belvini.de,http://www.belvini.de/content.php/coID/299/kundenmeinungen.html
www.belvini.de,http://www.belvini.de/weingueter
www.belvini.de,http://www.belvini.de/filter/cID/10/country/suedafrika.137.html
```

While running the code, I am getting an exception:

```
 Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 935 in stage 3.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 935.3 in stage 3.0 (TID 1883, node27.ib, executor 248): 
java.net.MalformedURLException: For input string: "RC-a-shops.de"
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:627)
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:490)
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:439)
```

RDD has around 1 Million edges and I'm running it in a cluster. 
Can someone please suggest how to get rid of this exception

Comment: Can you also provide the data? A sample from edges would help. Especially helpful if you can isolate the row that throws the exception.

Comment: It's a daring assumption, but... Have you tried prepending "http://" to the url?

Comment: Hi @Metropolis As I said I'm running it in a cluster. I'm not exactly sure where this exception is happening

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I updated the post now. Even if the URL begins with http its throwing an exception

Comment: What, is *that* the original exception message, copied byte by byte? The code `new URL("<this is your url>")` leads to the message 
`java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: <this is your url>`. That means that something in your program is feeding the string "someURL" to the `URL` constructor. This is obviously nonsense. If this is the case, your code excerpt and your examples seem irrelevant for the problem. We already knew that "someURL" is not a valid URL. The question should be: where does the string "someURL" come from?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin someURL is not actually an URL.I typed it myself to denote random URL. I will update the exception with the relevant URL in a while.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I tried your suggestion and posted the exact exception too.

Comment: Your last update contradicts your previous statement that "if the URL begins with http its throwing an exception".  Obviously, "RC-a-shops.de" is not a valid URL, and the exception tells you exactly that. If you feed some random garbage to the URL constructor, it will not miraculously turn it into a valid url. Instead, it will throw the exception. That's absolutely normal. So, what's your question is even about?

Comment: Ya I understand that its not a valid url. In that case I want that invalid url to be ignored from retrieving the host and exception should not be thrown. Please tell me if you have any idea of how to do that

Comment: did you try catching the exception?

Comment: @gregghz yes it's working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: The question was edited to include what looks like a well-formed URL in the MalformedURLException. Regardless, my answer stands. The docs for URL suggest it will only throw MalformedURLException when the url is invalid in someway. More complete output would help in debugging this issue.

```
MalformedURLException - if no protocol is specified, or an unknown protocol is found, or spec is null.
```

---

It looks like your `src` doesn't include the protocol of the URL. You need something like

```
http://whatever.com/nlp-agm.php
```

not just `nlp-agm.php`.

A URL must be of the form

```
<scheme>://<authority><path>?<query>#<fragment>
```

where `<scheme>` is required. `new java.net.URL` will throw `MalformedURLException` if the scheme is invalid or not specified. See more here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#URL(java.lang.String)

Comment: Hi I'm running it in a cluster. I don't have any output right now. Please let me know how can i resolve this

Comment: @ashwini I really can't help you further. You haven't posted the exact error you get. I have pointed you to documentation on why MalformedURLException will be thrown. Study that to understand where this error comes from.

Answer (score 0):

The java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol exception is also thrown when you have quotes in your string:

```
new Url("\"http:www.example.com\"")
```